# Protobuf data deserializing error in swift

Tags: ios, swift, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to deserialize response data from POST query. But my proto deserializer returns error:

```
'InvalidProtocolBuffer', reason: 'Invalid Tag: last tag 76'
```

Here is response string from rest client:

```
"EJMDGhnQlNC+0YHRgtGD0L8g0LfQsNC60YDRi9GC"
```

and here how i'm creating data from this string:

```
let data = dataString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
```

And parse it:

```
var _deData = MobileGetNewsResponse.parseFromData(jsonData!)
```

Any suggestions to resolve this problem?

Comment: Not enough information. Your error is in the parser, and we have no info about that.

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't to place whole parser code here. I Thought some one already had this kind of errors, and tell me^ where I need to work to resolve this problem. Parser is auto generated file, can it work with errors?

Comment: You should isolate the error from the serializer and post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"EJMDGhnQlNC+0YHRgtGD0L8g0LfQsNC60YDRi9GC"
```

This data is not, itself, a protobuf. It appears that it may be a base64-encoded protobuf. You need to base64-decode it first, then pass it to the protobuf parser.

Keep in mind that protobufs are raw bytes, not text. You should never attempt to store a raw protobuf in a string, nor attempt to interpret it as Unicode or UTF-8. It's just bytes. (base64 is one way of turning bytes into text.)

I'm also concerned about this line:

```
var _deData = MobileGetNewsResponse.parseFromData(jsonData!)
```

JSON and Protobufs are two completely different formats. You should not be attempting to parse a protobuf as JSON nor vice versa.